# Converting HTML Element into 'Node' type

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a HTML project. Basically saving HTML nodes to a JavaScript's Object to append them inside a element. Here's my HTML, JavaScript and the error.

**HTML**

```
...
    <div id="holder"></div>
...
```

**JavaScript**

```
var _handler = {};
var _holder = document.getElementById('holder');
var some_example = [{"id":"item_1"}, {"id":"item_2"}]

function create(tag, id) { /*Created a DOMObject */
    var elem = document.createElement(tag);
    _handler[id] = elem;
}
function spawn() {
   for (var k in _handler) {
       _holder.appendChild(_handler[k]); //<----- Here's the error occurring, given at very last.
   }
}
function main() { /* Main function */
    for (var x=0;x < some_example.length;x++) {
         create('div', some_example.id);
    }
    spawn();
}
```

Sorry for that little complicated script. Anyways, all the work going great but, `appendChild` does the *bobo* given below:

**Error**

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Hope, you guys have any idea. Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you use `hasOwnProperty` in your `for` loop.

```
for (var k in _handler) {
   if (_handler.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
       _holder.appendChild(_handler[k]); 
   }
}
```